# C# - Image as a clickable button

Tags: c#, winforms, image, button

I want to make some custom controls, with images as buttons. I don't want images ON buttons - I want to totally replace the button with an image read from a file.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [`PictureBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) control and use the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event on it to handle clicks.

Comment: Thanks, but here comes the problem: I need to handle MouseDown and other Mouse--- events.

Comment: @fonix232 - Did you look at the list of supported events? `MouseDown` and other mouse events are supported. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dk48x94%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You could use the image in the Button's `BackgroundImage` and change the `FlatStyle` to flat, and the colors of `FlatAppearance` `MouseDownBackColor` & `MouseOverBackColor` to transparent. It should look the same as a normal picture/picturebox with properties and events of a `Button`.